# Why does .obj exporting hang and output so many files?

Tags: export, obj

I frequently encounter this issue while exporting to .obj that causes blender to freeze (or sometimes crash) and output *hundreds* of copies of the same file.

[image: Hundreds of copies of the same file, exported by blender]

What's causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have selected the "Animation" option in the export options. You get a new file for every frame that the number of frames is set to in your output properties.

[image: Export Options]